# Understanding Data Characteristics for Linear Regression in R - Plotting Data Distribution Over the Regression Line

Tags: r, data-visualization, linear-regression

I am trying to understand how I might understand some properties of data when working through regression problems. Specifically, I would like to see the distribution of the data (y) characterized as a normal distribution at a given value of the regressor (x), and then plot this normal distribution (rotated 90 degrees) with the data and the regression line.

This is what I'm working with to try to figure things out (this code works fine):

```
library(BAS)  # for data
x <- bodyfat$Abdomen
y <- bodyfat$Bodyfat
dat <- data.frame(cbind(x, y))

# Linear model
fat.mod <- lm(y ~ x, data = dat)

# Plot of linear model and data
g <- ggplot(bodyfat, aes(x = Abdomen, y = Bodyfat)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
g
```

What I would like to see is an image like this: [image: this example], but for x values that I could specify (maybe with some spread in x?). With the plot, I would like to see the characteristics of the overlaid distribution (mean and standard deviation or variance). Making the assumption that the data is normally distributed about the regression line is OK.

Where I really fall apart is if I specify a point that is not explicitly in the data (e.g., the mean).

Any thoughts on this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was really non-trivial. Here's the solution (clearly taken from Dr. Kurz' work *Doing Bayesian Data Analysis in brms and the tidyverse*)

```
library(tidyverse)

# Draws per panel
n_draw <- 500

d <-
  data.frame(panel = rep(letters[1:2], 
     each = n_draw),
     x = c(runif(n = n_draw, min = -10, max = 10), 
     rnorm(n = n_draw / 2, mean = -7, sd = 2), 
     rnorm(n = n_draw / 2,  mean = 3, sd = 2))) %>% 
          mutate(y = 10 + 2 * x + rnorm(n = n(), 
          mean = 0, sd = 2))
```

Create a separate dataframe for rotated Gaussians:

```
# Define the x values from which the normal curves come
curves <- data.frame(x = seq(from = -7.5, to = 7.5, 
     length.out = 4)) %>%
  
# Use a linear relation (10 + 2x here) to compute an expected y for x
     mutate(y_mean = 10 + (2 * x)) %>%
  
# Based on a normal distribution with mean `y_mean` and a standard deviation of 2, compute the 95% intervals
     mutate(ll = qnorm(0.025, mean = y_mean, sd = 2), 
          ul = qnorm(0.975, mean = y_mean, sd = 2)) %>%
  
# Use the interval to make a series of y values
     mutate(y = map2(ll, ul, seq, length.out = 100)) %>%
  
# This must be `unnest()`ed
     unnest(y) %>%
  
# Calculate density values
     mutate(density = map2_dbl(y, y_mean, dnorm, 
          sd = 2)) %>%
  
# Rescale densities wider; redefine the x column 
     mutate(x = x - density * 2 / max(density))
```

Then plot:

```
d %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) -> g
g <- g + geom_point(size = 1/3, alpha = 1/3)
g <- g + stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE, 
        color = "red", linetype = 2)
g <- g + geom_path(data = curves, aes(group = y_mean),
            size = 1, color = "blue") 
g <- g + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-10, 10),
        ylim = c(-10, 30)) 
g <- g + theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank()) 
g
```

The resulting graphic is: [image: Gaussians characterizing data on linear fit]